# Removing Unecessary DNS Records?

Tags: server, dns, hosting, web-hosting, record

I'm looking at reducing DNS lookups on my website and I'm looking to see which DNS records I should keep or remove.

I have no idea how to decide which records aren't needed versus the records that are needed.

I have my settings to redirect all instances of my domain to the NON-www version, with HTTPS active throughout the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

If the Aim is to reduce the DNS lookups then you can achieve that by

1. Simply increase the TTL (expire) time, it will reduce the lookups drastically, though the downside is that whenever there is any change in the records, the updation will also take that much more time.

The lookups are proportionate to the traffic you get on your webpages, so if you don't see that much traffic and lookups are high, then there is something wrong in it.

About identifying unused DNS records, as a practice you should immediately remove the unused records as soon as you stop your service. Otherwise all records added in your DNS might be getting used. So, you might want to re-think on this.